# Rip off of Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web applications inspired by Stack Exchange's system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system)

While Googling, I found [a site](http://answers.unity3d.com/index.html) that is basically the same as a Stack Exchange site. What's up with this?

Comment: You only found [one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2267/52738)? ;)